# Merging entity with Play! framework and JPA silently failed

Tags: postgresql, jpa, playframework-2.0, hibernate-entitymanager

I've been looking around and around without finding any topics related to my situation.

I'm using:

- Play! framework v2.5.3 in Java
- Hibernate EntityManager v5.1.0.Final
- Hibernate JPA 2.1 API v1.0.0.Final
- PostgreSQL 9.4

Here the route called with AJAX:

```
PUT /admin/entity/:id
```

Which is bound to:

```
controllers.Entity.update(id: Long)
```

Here how I handle the update request:

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public Result update(final long id) {
  EntityManager em = _jpa.em("default");
  DynamicForm form = _formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
  models.Entity entity;

  entity = em.find(models.Entity.class, id);
  if (entity == null)
    return badRequest();
  entity.update(em, form);
  em.merge(entity);
  return ok();
```

The method `update` of `Entity` change values of the class attributes which are basically String attributes.

My issue: nothing get updated while still executing this piece of code.
I enable SQL log which only display the SELECT query corresponding to `em.find()` method call. Nothing related to an UPDATE query.

I've been using JPA/EntityManager with Play! for others projects (but with lower version of the framework) without facing this kind of problem.

Any idea why nothing get merged ?

> I've been able to fix this issue by writing following piece of code inside
>   `models.Entity.update`:
>
> em.getTransaction.begin();
>      Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE entity SET value = :v WHERE id = :id");
>      query.setParameter("value", value);
>      query.setParameter("id", id);
>      query.executeUpdate();
>      em.getTransaction.commit();
>
> But even if this is working, that's not the way how thing should be done... It
>   doesn't make coffee at all!

Edit: this solution do not work anymore....

I really don't know what I'm doing bad, if any body has an idea about this issue, you're help would be much appreciated.